# What could cause the slave not to send LL_START_ENC_RSP during BLE encryption procedure ?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

During the encryption procedure of a BLE connection, the master and the slave perform a 3-way handshake to validate the encryption. I am facing a case where the slave does not send the last part of this handshake, i.e. the message LL_START_ENC_RSP which is in red in the following schematic of this handshake :

[image]

Is there a specified reason for this to happen ? By specified I mean a reason that is not implementation specific.

The BLE Core Spec 4.2 tells this :

> When the Link Layer of the slave receives an LL_START_ENC_RSP PDU it
>   shall transmit an LL_START_ENC_RSP PDU. This packet shall be sent
>   encrypted.

But this does not specify any condition for the slave not to send this packet.

Would it be possible at this point that the slave thinks it has the Long Term Key associated with the current Master (because if it wasn't the case the slave wouldn't have started the 3-way handshake, right ?), but its LTK is incorrect and the decryption fails ? If it happened, wouldn't there be a disconnection message, instead of nothing ?

As I am pretty new to BLE I have no idea how to analyze or interpret this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated. The presence and the absence of the messages has been observed with the help of a BLE sniffer.

Note : Image 1 is a reproduction of Figure 7-26 of the book : Bluetooth Low Energy The Developer's handbook by Robin Heydon.

Comment: What is the bluetooth stack/hardware you have?

Comment: This is an information I cannot share (company policy), that's why I was asking for an implementation agnostic reason. I have the beginning of an answer, it seems that the first LL_START_ENC_RSP from the Master cannot be decrypted by the slave, but the reason remain vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec, the third message shall always be sent. If it is not sent, there is a bug in the implementation.

If the slave has the wrong LTK, the slave will not accept the LL_START_ENC_RSP from the master. If this happens, the link will be dropped after the supervision timeout since the slave will never acknowledge that packet.

Note that in order for a sniffer to successfully decrypt a packet, it needs to know the LTK. Nordic's sniffer program will catch the LTK if the sniffer runs during the pairing process.